# How can I implement an interface for the union of 2 (or more) types?

Tags: go

To be more concrete:

I have 2 Readers. One I get from os.Open("someExistingFile") and the other one from strings.NewReader("hello world").

One of them implemets Name(), the other one doesn't. I want to either make the other one also implement Name() (e.g. returning "") or (preferred) only call Name() if the type of the actual parameter supports it.

I hope the code fragment below indicates clearly what I want to solve.

I played around with different receivers, even with reflection but I didn't get to the point ...

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    stringReader := strings.NewReader("hello world")
    fileReader, _ := os.Open("someExistingFile") // error handling omitted
    fileReader.Name()

    printFilenameIfReaderIsFile(stringReader)
    printFilenameIfReaderIsFile(fileReader)
}

func printFilenameIfReaderIsFile(reader io.Reader) {
    // here I want to ...
    // ... either check if this reader is of type os.File and in this case call its Name() method (preferred)
    // ... or use a custom type instead of io.Reader.
    //     This type's Name() method should return the filename for fileReader and nil for stringReader.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [type switch](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch) control structure.

Your `printFilenameIfReaderIsFile` function should look like (not actually checked):

```golang
func printFilenameIfReaderIsFile(reader io.Reader) {
  switch f := reader.(type) {
    case *os.File:
      // f is now *os.File (not a os.File!)
      fmt.Printf("%s\n", f.Name())
  }
}
```

EDIT: Don't forget, that `os.Open` returns a `*os.File` instead of an `os.File` [see docs](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open)!

Comment: this block gives an error, I'm currently testing. I haven't used it before , but maybe you can fix it and edit your code

Comment: It's funny, because this was my very first attempt. It doesn't work because go says correctly: "Impossible type switch case: 'os.File' does not implement 'io.Reader'"

Comment: os.File is actually an *os.File, and you have to import all necessary packages

Comment: Go Playgrounds don't support files, but at least it compiles... https://play.golang.org/p/ApPuB33iDrd

Comment: Wow! That's it. Obviously both of us missed the * - but you noticed it while I didn't :-)
Thanks, now it works

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked. Would you consider marking it as the accepted answer, by clicking the checkmark? Thanks.